# Using gensub doesn't replace the match

Tags: awk

I have a tab-separated file, and the first column contains entries like this:

```
sp|O00253|AGRP_HUMAN
```

I am trying to use `awk` to output a new file containing only the text between the `|`s in column 1 and the rest of the text unchanged in the remaining columns.

The regex

```
/\w{2}\|(\w+)\|\w+/
```

matches the desired text (`O00253`) in capture group `$1`, but I can't get `awk` to replace the output using `gensub`.

I have tried numerous iterations around the lines below, but everything just returns the unchanged capture group.

```
awk 'gensub(/\w{2}\|(\w+)\|\w+/,"\\1","g",$1) {print}'

awk '{print gensub(/\w{2}\|(\w+)\|\w+/,"\\1","g",$0)}'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: with your second command, `echo "xx|foo|yy bar" | awk '{print gensub(...)}'  ` prints `foo bar` to me (GNU Awk 4.1.1), which looks like what you wanted if I understood correctly? Or did you mean you wanted to delete the part between the pipe symbols?

Comment: I'm running these commands via ssh into a cluster, and noticed the awk version is quite old (GNU Awk 3.1.8). That probably explains why the second command didn't work for me.

Comment: FYI gawk 3.1.7 (on CentOS 6) supports `{N}` in regexp only with option `--re-interval` or `--posix` and the latter disables `gensub` which is gawk-only. Without that `/\w\w\|(\w+)\|\w+/` works, but I'd prefer the `split` method you already accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 2nd solution works OK here. Your 1st one does not because `gensub`

> returns the modified string as the result of the function and the
>   *original target string is not changed*.[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

You could assign the result to a variable and then update `$1` e.g.

```
awk '{x=gensub(/\w{2}\|(\w+)\|\w+/,"\\1","1",$1);$1=x};1' infile
```

although I'd do it like this:

```
awk '{split($1,arr,"|");$1=arr[2]};1' infile
```

Comment: awk using split (your second example) worked perfectly, thanks!